# Flutter app does not have a Runner/Runner

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I am following [firebase docs instructions to add firebase to my flutter ios app.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios)

In regards to placing the GoogleService-Info.plist, it mentions..

> Using XCode, move the file into the Runner/Runner directory of your
> Flutter app.

The problem is, that my app does not have a Runner/Runner directory. My app does have an ios/Runner directory. Should I create an ios/Runner/Runner directory?

Comment: run `flutter create .` it will create the missing files in your project

Comment: In ios folder, you'll find Runner.xcodeproj. Open that in Xcode. In Xcode, in the left, right-click on Runner and add file, and add the GoogleService-Info.plist there. It's been a while, but I think only in Xcode, you'll see the Runner/Runner directory, and you'll have to add the file in Xcode if ya don't wanna encounter an error nowadays.